# Ionic React.js i need to pass an array of images so i can add a next and previous to the modal

Tags: reactjs, filter, modal-dialog

[Side by side of the thumbnail and the modal which opens][1]

In order to get to this code(ProductImagesItem)I have entered the following code:
{ProductImages.filter((pi) => pi.pageName === 'ST1').map((pi) => {return <ProductImagesItem key={pi.id}productImages={pi}>;
})}

However, I'm not too sure how to get the next and previous images as ProductImagesItems only deals with the individual objects not an array of objects. I believe I need to pass an array of the filtered Product Images but I'm unsure how to do so and whether I could then update the current modal with prev/next objects data.

Any help would be appreciated

[This ProductImagesItem - where the individual images can be viewed via a modal.]
ProductImagesItem

```
import {
  IonItem,
  IonThumbnail,
  IonImg,
  IonContent,
  IonModal,
  IonButton,
  IonButtons,
  IonHeader,
  IonToolbar,
  } from '@ionic/react';
import { Images } from '../data/ProductImages';
import './ProductImagesItem.css';
import { TransformWrapper, TransformComponent } from "react-zoom-pan-pinch";

interface ProductImagesItemProps {
    productImages: Images;
}

const ProductImagesItem: React.FC<ProductImagesItemProps> = ({ productImages}) => {
  const [showModal, setShowModal] = useState(false);
  
   const prevImage = () =>{
   }

    const nextImage = () =>{
      
   }

  return (
        <IonItem id="prodImgItem" >          
          <IonThumbnail id="prodImage" slot="start">
            <IonImg class="productImgBtn" id={"modal-" + productImages.id.toString()} onClick={() => setShowModal(true)} src={productImages.src} />
            <IonModal isOpen={showModal} cssClass='productModal'>
              <IonHeader translucent>
            <IonToolbar>
              <IonButtons slot="end">
                <IonButton  color="dark" id={"close-btn-" + productImages.id.toString()} onClick={() => setShowModal(false)}>Close</IonButton>
              </IonButtons>
            </IonToolbar>
          </IonHeader>
          <IonContent>
          <IonSlides pager={true} options={slideOpts}>
            <IonSlide>
            <TransformWrapper>
          <TransformComponent>
          <img src={productImages.src} alt="productImage" />
          </TransformComponent>
          </TransformWrapper>
            </IonSlide>
          </IonSlides>
            <p style={{marginTop:"1px"}} id="prodTitle">
              {productImages.title}
            </p>
          </IonContent>
          </IonModal>
        </IonThumbnail>
      </IonItem>
  );
  
};

export default ProductImagesItem;


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/b5H96.jpg
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5sb6Q.jpg
```

Comment: Could you share code instead of image of code.

Comment: I've added that now. I am quite new to this so I'm happy to explain anything in more detail

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me as though this component handles just one image, and that you have a line in the JSX of a higher component something like the following, where you pass a prop containing the data for one image to be displayed:

```
<ProductImagesItem productImages={dataObjectForOneImage} />
// productImages should be singular - productImage
```

In which case it is this higher component where your prev/next control needs to be, and you then pass a different set of data from your images array, for the 'current' required image, to your ProductImagesItem component.

Comment: Right if I understand correctly, I need to pass the prev/next image data from within the map () function. Like so:

Comment: <IonList id="productGalleryls">
          {ProductImages.filter((pi) => pi.pageName === 'ST1').map((pi, index) => {
            const prevImage = ProductImages[index - 1];
            const nextImage = ProductImages[index + 1];
          return (
          <React.Fragment key={pi.id}>
            <ProductImagesItem  productImages={prevImage}/>
            <ProductImagesItem  productImages={pi}/>
            <ProductImagesItem  productImages={nextImage}/>
          </React.Fragment>
          ); 
          })}
        </IonList>

Comment: I see, so you're trying to display a next a previous image, rather than prev/next buttons. So you're bit of code looks about right, have you tried it? Make sure you take care of the beginning and end of the array so that index - 1 and + 1 don't error.

Comment: No sorry, I do need the prev/next buttons. I'm just unsure how I would go about passing the array of images (including the prev and next) so that buttons can work.

Comment: Hi @pete-dbd, I was wondering how you were getting on with this, and whether you still need help with it? Sorry, I've not had the time too reply earlier. It would be helpful to me if you could give me a bit more info on how this part of your app should work and look like, and I'll try and help over the weekend, if you need it.

Comment: Hi, No worries at all. I have managed to make some progress with adding in the buttons which function as they should but I have done it by using vanila js so not too sure if that is best practice. I had added in two buttons which then trigger the below functions in order to go to the next/ previous image modal

Comment: function previousSlide(id){
  console.log(id);
  document.getElementById("close-btn-" + id.toString()).click();
  id--;
  document.getElementById("modal-" + (id).toString()).click(); 
}
function nextSlide(id){
  console.log(id);
  document.getElementById("close-btn-" + id.toString()).click();
  id++;
  document.getElementById("modal-" + (id).toString()).click();
}

Comment: So, having looked at the code a bit more, are you trying to show a grid of thumbnails and then when you click on one it shows that image in the modal, along with the next/prev buttons? Then, you can click next and prev in the modal to view other images. When you close the modal you're back to the thumnails? Is that how this should work? I assume the data is an array of object? Can you an example to your post please.

Comment: That's correct, yes. Looking back at it, it would probably be better to have a slider element to implement this. I have updated the code accordingly and added in an image for you example but struggling now to get the array of images across to the ProductImagesItem.tsx component